# 301 Redirect reg expression in htaccess

Tags: regex, .htaccess, redirect

I'm trying to redirect http://www.domain.com/post/155851321646/post-slug

to http://www.kaleandcaramel.com/post-slug

(this is actually redirecting old Tumblr URLs to Wordpress URLs)

the closest I came was this:

```
RewriteRule ^/?post/([0-9]+).(.*?)$ http://www.domain.com/$2 [L,R=301]
```

but it's not working.

Comment: How exactly is it not working?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this instead:

```
RewriteRule ^post/[0-9]+/([^/]+)$ http://www.domain.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Let me know any problems.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what url will be produced for `http://www.domain.com/post/155851321646/` will it be just `http://www.domain.com/`?

Comment: It would be ignored, because something is currently required after that forward slash to match successfully. What would you prefer?

Comment: I think this is exactly what OP meant, thank you for explaining.

Comment: that's exactly what I needed. thank you!
(and http://www.domain.com/post/155851321646/ should be ignored)