# multiple 301 redirects after regex

Tags: regex, .htaccess, redirect

I have a rewrite rule using regex [that's working fine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42035836/301-redirect-reg-expression-in-htaccess).
but now I want to add add'l 301 redirects that are not.

```
RewriteRule ^post/[0-9]+/([^/]+)$ http://example.com/$1 [L,R=301]

RedirectMatch 301 /some-other-old-slug http://example.com/category/some-new-slug-based-on-some-other-old-slug
```

the first one works, the second one doesn't. how come?

EDIT: changing to Redirect made it work. but I actually need both the rewrite rule plus the occasional slug change. ex:

example.com/post/123345/old-slug to example.com/old-slug-edited.
it seems that the first rewrite rule does it's trick and the second will be ignored.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That should work fine. You don't need `RedirectMatch` to specify an exact URI. Just use `Redirect`. But I think you simply made a spelling mistake when testing, or some other problem that didn't come through when you simplified to ask the question. No reason this wouldn't work.

**Update**

For your edge cases, process them first with mod_rewrite. I have opted to do this in a `RewriteCond` to improve legibility and so the URI can be pasted in without escaping special characters. Add one pair for each edge case:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} =/post/123456789/edge-case
RewriteRule ^ http://example.com/new-edge-case-slug [L,R=301]

RewriteRule ^post/[0-9]+/([^/]+)$ http://domain.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: indeed, it works. at least after I use Redirect. however, some edge cases require a redirect of the original RewriteRule AND a slightly different slug! I edited the original question.

Comment: I added a solution for your edge cases.

Comment: this is good. thank you. and so timely. wish I could upvote twice.